# How to use BeautifulSoup to extract the value in id

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get "e7dda36c5cf592d18e50a44711ea636b", And how to do it.

```html
<a class="link" href="javascript:void(0);" id="e7dda36c5cf592d18e50a44711ea636b">
<p class="title">aaaaaaaaaa</p>
<p class="time">2020-10-28</p>
<span class="last">bbbbbbb</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Did you try anything before you asked the question? If so, please provide your `code` otherwise your question will get downvoted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer to solve my question.

```
for tag in soup.find_all(class_="bookmark blurb group"):
    print tag.get('id')
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
data = #your html
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
tag = soup.a
id = tag.attrs["id"]
```